# Pass parameters from command line to a PHP Class and Functions script

Tags: php, command-line, parameter-passing, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I want to pass the variable value that is $n through the command line for example `$ php fibo.php 6`

```
<?php
    class fibo
    {
    function fibo1($n)
    {
        $first  =   0;
        $second =   1;
        echo "Fibonacci Series \n";
        echo $first." ".$second." ";
        $n  =   $argv[1];
        for ($i=2; $i < $n ; $i++) 
        { 

            $third  =   $first  +   $second;
            echo $third." ";

            $first  =   $second;
            $second =   $third;
        }  
    }   
}
    fibo::fibo1($n);  
?>
```

And I get this output

`$ php fibo.php 6`

Fibonacci Series
0 1

But after removing class and function it works.
e.g.

`$ php fibo.php 10`

```
Fibonacci Series

0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
class fibo
    { 
    function fibo1($n)
    {
        $first  =   0;
        $second =   1;
        echo "Fibonacci Series \n";
        echo $first." ".$second." ";

        for ($i=2; $i < $n ; $i++) 
        { 

            $third  =   $first  +   $second;
            echo $third." ";

            $first  =   $second;
            $second =   $third;
        } 
    }   
}
    $n=getopt(null, ["n:"]);
    fibo::fibo1($n['n']);
```

Run This Command
$ php fibo.php --n=6